# moving a div with JS (edited)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to move a div with JS accessing the div's css properties when I press the arrow keys.
I've achieved to trigger an alert when I press a key but the div is not moving.This is the all my code:

EDIT: ive changed my JS script. now it does move 10px to the left (by erasing the transform property from the CSS) but it only does it once. i tried to fix it with a counter witch multiplies the 10px by the times i've clicked the key, still does it only once.

```js
   

function mover(event) {
capa=document.getElementById("movil");
left=-10;
Ltimes=1;
switch (event.keyCode) {
    case 37:
        // alert("works");
        capa.style.transform ="translateX("+left*Ltimes+"px)";
        Ltimes++;
        break;
    case "ArrowRight":

        break;
    case "ArrowUp":

        break;
    case "ArrowDown":

        break;

    default:
        break;
}


}
```

```css
div#movil {
  background-color: khaki;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#arriba {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

div#abajo {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

div#centro {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

div#izq {
  position: absolute;
}

div#der {
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body onkeydown="mover(event)">
  <div id="movil">
    <div id="arriba">
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </div>
    <div id="abajo">
      <button>+</button>
      <button>-</button>
    </div>
    <div id="centro">
      <div id="izq">
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
      </div>
      <div id="der">
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <input type="text" id="a">
</body>
```

As I said I've achieved to trigger the "works" alert but the div won't move.

PS: ignore the buttons I'll make them make the div bigger or smaller later on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`capa.style.transform ="translateX(-10px)";` Looks to be what you meant

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translateX for reference

```js
capa = document.getElementById("movil");
function mover(event) {
    
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            alert("works");
            capa.style.transform ="translateX(-10px)";
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":

            break;
        case "ArrowUp":

            break;
        case "ArrowDown":

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    
}
```

```css
div#movil {
    background-color: khaki;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#arriba {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

div#abajo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div#centro {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

div#izq {
    position: absolute;
}

div#der {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="mover(event)">
    <div id="movil">
        <div id="arriba">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="abajo">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="centro">
            <div id="izq">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
            <div id="der">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
           
        </div>

       
       
       
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="a">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the fast answer. ive already changed that still not working so i tried to acces to the element by id inside the function and it does move now. the problem now is that it is moving only one time to the right and down and it won't move again when key pressed.

`function mover(event) {
    capa=document.getElementById("movil");
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            alert("works");
            capa.style.transform ="translateX(-10px)";
            break;
`

Comment: Well, first you need to define a variable for increment or decrement, your current code is constantly setting transformX(-10px) and if you enter any button profusely it won't work the 2nd time.

Comment: yes MD i've  noticed that and changed the function (the code is edited) still moves it only once

Comment: The variable will need defined outside of the method otherwise everytime method is called it will be reset

Comment: That is `Ltimes` will need moved

Comment: omg  I feel so stupid for not seeing that i think i need a rest for today...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working example by by getting the left/top property value and minus a set amount of pixels then reapply the value.

1. getComputedStyle -> required if loading external css
2. getPropertyValue -> find what the current left or top value is.
3. remove any letters (px) from start/end with .match() and .join()
4. parse all of the above as an integer so we can remove or add a number to it
5. add or remove our "pxToMove" value
6. convert all that back to a string and add the "px" to the end.

```js
capa = document.getElementById("movil");
function mover(event) {

    var style = getComputedStyle(capa);
    var pxToMove = 10;
    
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            //alert("works");
            capa.style.left= (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left").match(/\d/g).join("")) - pxToMove).toString()+"px";
            break;
        case 39:
            capa.style.left= (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("left").match(/\d/g).join("")) + pxToMove).toString()+"px";
            break;
        case 38:
            capa.style.top= (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top").match(/\d/g).join("")) - pxToMove).toString()+"px";
            break;
        case 40:
            capa.style.top= (parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("top").match(/\d/g).join("")) + pxToMove).toString()+"px";
            break;

        default:
            alert(event.keyCode);
            break;
    }

    
}
```

```css
div#movil {
    background-color: khaki;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

div#arriba {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

div#abajo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div#centro {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

div#izq {
    position: absolute;
}

div#der {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="mover(event)">
    <div id="movil">
        <div id="arriba">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="abajo">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="centro">
            <div id="izq">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
            <div id="der">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
           
        </div>

       
       
       
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="a">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm really greatefull for all the comments this is the final working code:

```js
var left=-10;
var Ltimes=1;
function mover(event) {
    capa=document.getElementById("movil");
    
    switch (event.keyCode) {
        case 37:
            // alert("works");
            capa.style.transform ="translateX("+left*Ltimes+"px)";
            Ltimes++;
            break;
        case "ArrowRight":

            break;
        case "ArrowUp":

            break;
        case "ArrowDown":

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    
}
```

```css
div#movil {
    background-color: khaki;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /* transform: translate(-50%, -50%); */
}

div#arriba {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
}

div#abajo {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}

div#centro {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translate(0, -50%);
}

div#izq {
    position: absolute;
}

div#der {
    right: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="js.js"></script>
</head>
<body onkeydown="mover(event)">
    <div id="movil">
        <div id="arriba">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="abajo">
            <button>+</button>
            <button>-</button>
        </div>
        <div id="centro">
            <div id="izq">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
            <div id="der">
                <button>+</button>
                <button>-</button>
            </div>
           
        </div>

       
       
       
    </div>
    <input type="text" id="a">
</body>
</html>
```